# VBA code to select certain value in SAP GUI then replace with new value

Tags: vba, scripting, sap-gui

I am needing assistance with the proper code for an SAP GUI script. I am needing to select a certain value "T09k.42A" and replace with "T09k.59E". The value is not always on the same line, which is where I am hitting a roadblock.

[code fo far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrQm.jpg) [SAP example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyOQd.jpg) [SAP example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0FRV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the Row value with a variable to cycle through all rows and find the value you are looking to change.  With this in mind, you may have to use the description row and look for a blank to end the loop.

```
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCPDITCTRL_3400/ctxtPLPOD-ARBPL[2,2]")
```

is the same as

```
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCPDITCTRL_3400/ctxtPLPOD-ARBPL[2," & "2" & "]")
```

replace the second number with a variable

```
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCPDITCTRL_3400/ctxtPLPOD-ARBPL[2," & j & "]")
```

Now you can loop through to find the value you want to change

```
For j = 0 to 6 '7 visible rows in your picture
   If session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCPDITCTRL_3400/ctxtPLPOD-ARBPL[2," & j & "]").text = "T09k.42A" then
     session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCPDITCTRL_3400/ctxtPLPOD-ARBPL[2," & j & "]").text = "T09k.59E"
     session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCPDITCTRL_3400/ctxtPLPOD-ARBPL[2," & j & "]").setFocus
     session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
   End if
```